# Highlight window position with Alt-tab window switching (GNOME shell)

Tags: gnome-shell, application-switcher

When I switch windows in GNOME shell with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>, I find it really hard to distinguish between windows just from the little preview thumbnails.

Back in the old days, metacity (and Compiz, iirc) would draw a border or otherwise indicate the screen position of the window you were switching to.  Even better would be highlighting the window in some way.  Is there a way to do this with GNOME Shell?

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, GNOME Shell 3.28.

(Related, but I'm just hoping for an outline or highlight, not necessarily a window preview: [Is there a window switcher for GNOME that shows the actual window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125085/is-there-a-window-switcher-for-gnome-that-shows-the-actual-window))

Comment: Do you mean something like Alt+Esc? Switch windows directly.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't discovered that! That's way better, but my ideal would be to combine both of them.  It's nice to see the tabbing order at the same time.

Comment: Do you mean something like [Alt + `](https://askubuntu.com/a/908793/349837) for current application windows, or [like this with all windows](https://blogs.gnome.org/fmuellner/2018/10/11/the-future-of-alternatetab-and-why-you-need-not-worry/), using Alt+Tab?

Comment: I prefer the AlternateTab behavior, where Alt+Tab switches between all windows on the current workspace.  Although it seems like highlighting the window should work with either behavior.

Answer (score 5):

The [AATWS - Advanced Alt-Tab Window Switcher](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4412/advanced-alttab-window-switcher/) Gnome Extension does what you're asking I think. You can change the setting “Show Selected Window” to “Show Preview” and then as you cycle through windows with Alt-Tab, the current window is raised and a prominent border is added to the window so you can easily identify it.

Comment: Ooh, this looks excellent, thanks!  I'll give it a try as soon as I update to 22.04.