# ALT+TAB: selected app highlighting contrast nearly indistinguishable from background (dark-gray on black)

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, 22.04, accessibility, yaru

[Back in the days of 20.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yaru-theme/+bug/1871416), we managed to get the Yaru designers to improve the contrast of the `ALT+TAB` task switcher's selected app just in time for the release.

22.04 is out now and it looks like this has regressed, again...

[image: ALT+TAB on Ubuntu 22.04 - can you tell which app is selected (without reading the caption)?]

I admit I'm lucky to work in a bright office but the current contrast (dark gray on black) makes me squint every time I use the thing (and I use a good quality "productivity" monitor).

Hopefully there is a way to improve the contrast by editing some `.css` file?  If this is too hard (really?) I'd be happy to install an extension but don't feel I need to replace the whole UI as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1401153/145568).

Comment: Let me +1 this question/request (explicitly) with the hope that this may attract someone with a good answer. I suspect that many Ubuntu users suffer from this issue and it strikes me as odd that it wasn't dealt with yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the following issue `6907` on gitlab.gnome.org:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/6907

The following code by Chris Heywood does change the `dark-gray` by the color `white`:

Prerequisite, the Gnome extension ["User Themes"](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/) has to be installed.

(open a shell and you don't have to be 'root')

Activation in `white`:

```
# Create a theme which only modifies the app switcher CSS
mkdir -p ~/.themes/TempAppSwitcherContrastCludge/gnome-shell
echo ".switcher-list .item-box:selected { background: #f6f5f4; color: #241f31; }" > ~/.themes/TempAppSwitcherContrastCludge/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css
# Enable user themes shell extension
gnome-extensions enable user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
# Select the theme
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name TempAppSwitcherContrastCludge
```

Deactivation:

```
# Clear theme setting
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name ""
# Disable user themes extension
gnome-extensions disable user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
# Remove theme
rm -r ~/.themes/TempAppSwitcherContrastCludge
```

It was `tested`/`activated` on `23.10` and it works perfectly! I have also tested the `deactivation` working correctly.

Chris, if you read me, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're da man!  This is going to make many a users' day no doubt.  *Note* on 22.04, you'll need to use `dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/user-theme/name "'TempAppSwitcherContrastCludge'"` instead of `gsettings` on the last line (or use the extensions GUI). In any case, you'll need to have the "User Themes" extensions installed.
Still don't understand how the horrible out-of-box UX could make it through QA...

Comment: If anyone fancies something a little more subtle than the white colour proposed in the solution, you can vary it by adjusting the hex value for `background:` in the `echo` cmd above.  Use a picture editor like Pinta to grab the hex value that works for you.  I have mine set to `background: #5936B5;` (a sort of dark purple).  You'll need to switch the `user-theme` off and back to `TempAppSwitcherContrastCludge` in order to try different values w/o having to log out.

Comment: ["User Themes" extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/) required as mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the CSS file for your Gnome Shell theme to change the appearance of the `alt+taB` task switcher. The CSS file can be found in the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme` as well as in your home directory.

1. Open the file with a text editor:

   ```
   nano ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
   ```
2. Find the lines which resemble with:

   ```css
   .alt-tab-app-switcher {
       background-color: #333;
   }

   .alt-tab-app-switcher .selected {
       background-color: #555;
   }
   ```
3. Change the background colour for `.alt-tab-app-switcher .selected` with a lighter color. For example:

   ```css
   .alt-tab-app-switcher .selected {
       background-color: #ccc;
   }
   ```
4. You can use any CSS color code to set the background color. After making the changes, save the file and restart Gnome Shell (Alt +F2) for the changes to show effect.

   Note: Keep in mind that this is just an example and the actual styles in your CSS file may be different. It's would be a good idea to back up the original CSS file before making any changes.

Note that different Gnome Shell themes might have different styles for the `alt+tab` task switcher, so you may need to modify the CSS styles accordingly.

Good luck

Comment: Thank YOU for giving it a shot at long last!  Although it certainly appears to go in the right direction, those CSS files and classes are elusive on my 22.04 system: `grep -R alt-tab-app-switcher /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme ~/.config/gtk-*` returns nothing...

Comment: @sxc731 it requires some investigation. For example; the Yaru CSS file in my machine is `/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`; and I have also created an instance of it in my home directory by `mkdir ~/.themes; mkdir ~/.themes/Yaru
; mkdir ~/.themes/Yaru/gtk-3.0
; touch ~/.themes/Yaru/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` try to find the CSS file and do the necessary edits.

Comment: @AlwaysAvailable the content of my `/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` looks like this:
`@import url("resource:///com/ubuntu/themes/Yaru/3.0/gtk.css");`
If I add to this line the following:
`.alt-tab-app-switcher .selected {
    background-color: #ccc;
}`
then nothing changes. Any ideas why?

Comment: @AlwaysAvailable Have attempted this: `mkdir -p ~/.themes/Yaru/gtk-3.0 ; cat > ~/.themes/Yaru/gtk-3.0/gtk.css << EOF
.alt-tab-app-switcher .selected {
    background-color: #1fe6d8;
}
EOF`; followed by ALT+F2/r.  Ditto with `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`.  Neither produced the expected improvement.  `grep -R alt-tab-app-switcher /usr/share/themes/` produces no file that contains the CSS class you mention.  Did you get this to work on a "stock" Ubuntu 22.04 machine? I think it would help *a lot* of people if we could nail that!

Comment: @sxc731 It's possible that your changes to the GTK CSS file are being overridden by a different style rule that takes precedence. To investigate this, you could use a web inspector tool (such as the one built into Firefox or Chrome) to inspect the specific styles being applied to the ALT+TAB task switcher, and see if there are any conflicting or higher-priority style rules that are overriding your changes.

Comment: @sxc731 Another possibility is that the theme or style rules for the ALT+TAB task switcher may be handled differently or separately from the main GTK CSS file. You may need to look for a separate CSS file or configuration specific to the ALT+TAB task switcher or task switcher popup, and modify that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I am on Ubuntu 23.04 pretty much vanilla I think, and I couldn't find the token `alt-tab-app-switcher` either in `~/.themes` or in `/usr/share/themes`.

I'm not sure what's changed, there, but I did find another route. Following [this page](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/linux/change-gnome-them) (not as arduous as it looks, 5-10 minutes work):

- Installed GNOME shell browser integration
- Installed User-Themes Extension
- Download & install Dracula theme under ~/.themes
- sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks
- Log off/in to notice the new themes, I think, may not be necessary
- Open gnome-tweaks from console of Menu/search/tweaks
- Go to Appearance, and change 'Shell' (which probably says Default) to Dracula.
- This theme is now live, and looks similar to the default theme, similar enough that I can't see what's changed.
- Edit ~/.themes/Dracula*/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css.

Adjust that file as follows to turn the offending grey box red:

```
.switcher-list .item-box:selected {
    background-color: red; /*rgba(189, 147, 249, 0.5)*/
    color: #f8f8f2; }
```

[EDIT] Oh, PS, either switch the theme back and forth in gnome-tweaks or log out/in to effect the color change.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion to use a different theme; I was really after a way to fix this in with the stock Ubuntu "Yaru" theme.  FWIW, stock Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't have the `alt-tab-app-switcher` CSS class referenced in the other answer either; thus that answer doesn't work (which is why I haven't "accepted" it).

Comment: True, this isn't a direct answer to your question. I posted this more for folks like me who are desperate to solve this - this question is one of the most promising hits when googling the issue. I'm barely bothered at all how my screen looks, so Dracula for me is equivalent to Yaru (save for some rather groovy purple logout etc. buttons). I am very bothered by not being able to see what I'm doing, and my new bold red alt-tab highlight box is now bringing a smile to my face every time I switch tasks :). Now if only I could get back the old-style scrollbars that are as wide as my thumb...