# How to change color in the app switch window in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, customization, colors, gnome-color-manager

When I switch between applications using `ALT + TAB`, a small window appears in the middle of the screen and lets me choose another application.

My problem is that the color of the highlighted application is very similar to the others.

So, how can I change the color of the highlighted app in the settings?

My system specifications:

- OS Name: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- GNOME Version: 42.5
- Windowing System: X11

Comment: You are right about that lack in constrast. Question also raised here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406170/alttab-selected-app-highlighting-contrast-nearly-indistinguishable-from-backgr

Comment: A dismissed bug report here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/4109

Comment: Bug filed with Ubuntu here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yaru-theme/+bug/1871416

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ALT+TAB: selected app highlighting contrast nearly indistinguishable from background (dark-gray on black)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406170/alttab-selected-app-highlighting-contrast-nearly-indistinguishable-from-backgr)