# Cycling windows by click on dock program's icon

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, customization, ubuntu-dock

By now, when I click to an application in my dock it is minimized. But I would like to cycle through all open tabs of that application with this action.

I use to use the  <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd> hot keys to toggle between programs, however, by this, it show me the system activities while there is multiple tabs of the target application.

How could I change this behavior?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Ubuntu Dock" is forked from the extension "Dash to Dock", and accordingly uses it settings. Thus, you can change the behavour of "Ubuntu Dock" by editing the dconf settings of "Dash to dock", using `dconf-editor` (not installed by default in 18.04) or with the single command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'cycle-windows'
```

You can list all possible settings:

```
gsettings range org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action
```

Reset to the default setting with:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action
```

Comment: Oh thanks, man, was looking all over the internet for this. I installed a fresh OS and forgot the name of the setting.